# infinite loops on relationship @ManyToOne in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, relationship

I have two entities, `Country` and `Province`, with their data in a database. The relationship between them is established using the `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations, respectively.

When querying the data with Postman, the list of countries displays correctly, and in the case of Argentina, it shows the related provinces.

However, when attempting to view the provinces, which are linked to Country through the 'id_country' field, Postman returns an error. If I make the query in Google Chrome, it enters into an infinite loop when I include the 'getCountry()' method in the Province entity. However, if I comment out that method, I can see the data for the provinces, but I lose the ability to see the country to which each province belongs.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully retrieve both the list of countries and their associated provinces without encountering errors or infinite loops?

The entity 'Pais' is as follows

```
@Entity
public class Pais {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String nacionalidad;
    private String codigo;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pais", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Provincia> provincia;
    
    public Pais() {
    }
    
    public Pais(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String codigo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
```

The entity 'Provincia' is as follows

```
@Entity
public class Provincia {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String gentilicio;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pais")
    Pais pais;
    
    public Provincia() {
    }
    
    public Provincia(String nombre, String gentilicio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.gentilicio = gentilicio;
    }
```

Both entities have their corresponding imports and their getters and setters.

I need to see something like this when I want to see the results of the list of 'Provincia':

```
[ {
         "id": 1,
         "nombre": "Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires",
         "gentilicio": "Porteño",
         "Pais": "Argentina"
 } ]
```

But I get an infinite loop if I include the 'getCountry()' method in the `Province` entity

Comment: could you provide also stack trace that you get ?